# Apache Kerberos not Authenticating from Windows Client

Tags: apache, authentication, kerberos

With a number of great websites for reference, I setup an Apache 2.4 environment on Solaris 11 using the auth_gss_module for Kerberos authentication.  The problem I have is not being able to access an authorized page using IE, Chrome, or Firefox on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008.  I have been successful accessing the secured page with curl and python scripts and also Safari and Firefox browsers on OS X 10.10.  I have listed output from both successful and failed attempts with Kerberos authentication.   I am not sure if it might be a configuration setting within AD that needs to be changed or maybe a encryption difference.  I am looking for suggestions on what to do next.   Thank you..

A key tab was created for me by the AD admin and this is the contents of the key tab

```
 cyoull@host0ad903.abc.def.net:/local_apps/apache4/conf/certs$ klist -k host0ad903_keytab                                                                                                              
Keytab name: FILE:host0ad903_keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 HTTP/host0ad903.abc.def.net@ABC.DEF.NET
```

On OS X, this is the list of kerberos tickets from the klist command.

```
Chriss-MacBook-Air:~ chris$ klist
Credentials cache: API:EF1241C7-A883-44A8-9729-969775673BCA
        Principal: cyoull@ABC.DEF.NET

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Sep 25 07:22:52 2015  Sep 25 17:22:40 2015  krbtgt/ABC.DEF.NET@ABC.DEF.NET
Chriss-MacBook-Air:~ chris$ klist
Credentials cache: API:EF1241C7-A883-44A8-9729-969775673BCA
        Principal: cyoull@ABC.DEF.NET

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Sep 25 07:22:52 2015  Sep 25 17:22:40 2015  krbtgt/ABC.DEF.NET@ABC.DEF.NET
Sep 25 07:23:06 2015  Sep 25 17:22:40 2015  HTTP/host0ad903.abc.def.net@ABC.DEF.NET

Valid starting               Expires               Service principal
18/09/2015 10:17  18/09/2015 20:17  krbtgt/ABC.DEF.NET@ABC.DEF.NET
        renew until 25/09/2015 10:17, Etype(skey, tkt): ArcFour with HMAC/md5, AES-256 CTS mode with 96-bit SHA-1 HMAC 
18/09/2015 10:17  18/09/2015 20:17  HTTP/host0ad903.abc.def.net@ABC.DEF.NET
        renew until 25/09/2015 10:17, Etype(skey, tkt): ArcFour with HMAC/md5, ArcFour with HMAC/md5
```

This is the Apache log after successfully accessing the secured page with Kerberos authentication from Safari on OS X

```
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.348043 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24214:tid 18] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.93.68.187:56071] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.348054 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24214:tid 18] mod_auth_gss.c(632): [client 10.93.68.187:56071] No authentication data found
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.348063 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24214:tid 18] mod_auth_gss.c(592): [client 10.93.68.187:56071] note_gss_auth_failure: auth_name = <undefined>
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.590334 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.590347 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(334): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] authenticate_user_gss called
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.590362 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(373): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] Using keytab: KRB5_KTNAME=/local_apps/apache4/conf/certs/host0ad903_keytab
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.590508 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(411): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] Client wants GSS mech: spnego
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.590524 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(288): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] acquire_server_creds for HTTP@host0ad903.abc.def.net
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.621760 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(438): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] got server creds for: HTTP@host0ad903.abc.def.net
[Fri Sep 25 07:23:06.639432 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(549): [client 10.93.68.187:56073] Authenticated user (final result) : cyoull@ABC.DEF.NET
```

This is the Apache log file after a successful attempt with a Python script on Windows Server 2008

```
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.890889 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.890900 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(632): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] No authentication data found
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.890909 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(592): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] note_gss_auth_failure: auth_name = <undefined>
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.908047 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.908056 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(334): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] authenticate_user_gss called
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.908080 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(373): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] Using keytab: KRB5_KTNAME=/local_apps/apache4/conf/certs/host0ad903_keytab
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.908188 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(411): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] Client wants GSS mech: kerberos_v5
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.908203 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(288): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] acquire_server_creds for HTTP@host0ad903.abc.def.net
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.910360 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(438): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] got server creds for: HTTP/host0ad903.abc.def.net@ABC.DEF.NET
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.917847 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(524): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] Authenticated user before AuthGSSStripDomainAT: cyoull@ABC.DEF.NET
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.917863 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(533): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] Authenticated user before AuthGSSForceCase: coy
[Thu Sep 17 16:29:48.917873 2015] [core:debug] [pid 32125:tid 21] mod_auth_gss.c(549): [client 10.115.2.117:50526] Authenticated user (final result) : cyoull@ABC.DEF.NET
```

This is the Kerberos tickets on the Windows 7 client

```
U:\>klist
Current LogonId is 0:0xa84757
Cached Tickets: (2)
#0>     Client: cyoull @ ABC.DEF.NET
        Server: krbtgt/ABC.DEF.NET @ ABC.DEF.NET
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40e00000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent
        Start Time: 9/25/2015 9:19:28 (local)
        End Time:   9/25/2015 19:19:28 (local)
        Renew Time: 10/2/2015 9:19:28 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96

#1>     Client: cyoull @ ABC.DEF.NET
        Server: HTTP/host0ad903.abc.def.net @ ABC.DEF.NET
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x40a00000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent
        Start Time: 9/25/2015 9:19:30 (local)
        End Time:   9/25/2015 19:19:28 (local)
        Renew Time: 10/2/2015 9:19:28 (local)
        Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
```

Using the developer tools in Firefox I see three GET requests and in the apache log file it looks as if the kerberos negotiation tries more than once then fails with a 401 Unauthorized

```
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.205356 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.205366 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(632): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] No authentication data found
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.205374 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(592): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] note_gss_auth_failure: auth_name = <undefined>
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.471160 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.471170 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(334): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] authenticate_user_gss called
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.471187 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(373): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] Using keytab: KRB5_KTNAME=/local_apps/apache4/conf/certs/host0ad903_keytab
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.471290 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(411): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] Client wants GSS mech: spnego
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.471307 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(288): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] acquire_server_creds for HTTP@host0ad903.abc.def.net
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.474953 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(438): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] got server creds for: HTTP@host0ad903.abc.def.net
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.475143 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(650): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] Authentication failed.
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.475157 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(592): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] note_gss_auth_failure: auth_name = <undefined>
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.540288 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(620): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] gss_authenticate: type = GSSAPI
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.540296 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(334): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] authenticate_user_gss called
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.540310 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(373): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] Using keytab: KRB5_KTNAME=/local_apps/apache4/conf/certs/host0ad903_keytab
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.540344 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(411): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] Client wants GSS mech: <unknown>
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.540353 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(288): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] acquire_server_creds for HTTP@host0ad903.abc.def.net
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.543031 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(438): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] got server creds for: HTTP/host0ad903.abc.def.net@abc.def.net
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.543188 2015] [core:error] [pid 24150:tid 24] [client 10.211.8.122:52459] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Invalid token was supplied (Unknown error)
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.543336 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(650): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] Authentication failed.
[Fri Sep 25 08:54:28.543349 2015] [core:debug] [pid 24150:tid 24] mod_auth_gss.c(592): [client 10.211.8.122:52459] note_gss_auth_failure: auth_name = <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the web browsers on Windows to actually do HTTP Negotiate with this server? For example, in Firefox you need to set:

```
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris = abc.def.net
```

or another pattern that would match the URL. Chrome similarly has to be told to be willing to authenticate to the particular server, e.g. with:

```
--auth-server-whitelist="*.foo.com"
```

or via group policy.

If that’s not the problem, then please do this:

1. `ipconfig /flushdns`
2. `klist purge`
3. Run Wireshark and capture the HTTP, DNS, and Kerberos traffic during a failure (ports 80, 53, and 88).
4. Post the resulting pcap file.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your suggestions.  I had set Firefox up to do the HTTP Negotiate prior to my posting.  I was able to get a Wireshark capture but due to security, I am unable to post the pcap file without being able to change the host and domain strings.  If there is anything specific that you can suggest looking for in the capture, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Without being able to look at the data, there’s little I can do. All I can say is look for errors involving related DNS lookups, Kerberos exchanges with the KDCs, and in the WWW-Authenticate exchange in the HTTP connection. Of course, it may not be obvious to you what constitutes an error, or what a correct exchange would look like.

Comment: Generally, you should see:

> HTTP GET
< HTTP 401 with list of supported authentication methods, including Negotiate (SPNEGO/GSSAPI)
> HTTP GET (this time with Authenticate: Negotiate header)
< HTTP 200 (requested document, possible with another Authenticate: Negotiate header if the client requested mutual authentication).

There will be traffic with the KDCs if the client needs to acquire a ticket for the service first.